# Usar o Select2 para procurar estados e cidades

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Estou querendo melhorar a busca de cidades e estados.
Eu fiz essa dinâmica com o Select2:

```js
  /*************** Procurar estado ***************/
  $( ".estado" ).select2({    
   placeholder: "Estado",
   ajax: {

    url: "https://www.agenciamove.com.br/php/procurar_estados.php",
    
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
     return {
      q: params.term // search term
     };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
     // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
     // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
     // alter the remote JSON data
     return {
      results: data
     };
    },
    cache: true
   }
  }); 
  /*************** Procurar estado ***************/
  
  /*************** Procurar cidade ***************/
  $( ".cidade" ).select2({    
   placeholder: "Cidade",
   ajax: {

    url: "https://www.agenciamove.com.br/php/procurar_cidades.php?estado=26",      
    
    
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
     return {
      q: params.term // search term
     };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
     // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
     // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
     // alter the remote JSON data
     return {
      results: data
     };
    },
    cache: true
   }
  }); 
  /*************** Procurar cidade ***************/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="estado form-control" name="estado" id="estado" style="width: 50%";></select> 
<select class="cidade form-control" name="cidade" id="cidade" style="width: 50%";></select>
```

Na parte de procurar cidades, seria necessário enviar o id do estado (como no teste que fiz "procurar_cidades.php?estado=26").

Mas não estou encontrando uma forma para que isso aconteça.

Será que existe alguma forma de, depois de procurar o estado, a cidade inicie com o id do estado?

Comment: Seria bom se o endereço `https://www.agenciamove.com.br/php/procurar_estados.php` estivesse funcionando, pra te ajudar.

Comment: Deu uma mensagem de bloqueio daqui do Stack: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.agenciamove.com.br/php/procurar_estados.php. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://www.agenciamove.com.br/php/procurar_estados.php?q=sao. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Comment: Não é isso não.... Tá dando timeout mesmo. Nem estou rodando seu script... to só tentando fazer um get pelo postman

Comment: Fiz no codepen e dá o mesmo erro. Está funcionando, mas essa instrução está bloqueando o retorno.

Comment: Encontrei uma solução no stack em inglês. Pode-se adicionar o id dentro do return      return {
      estado_id: $(".estado").val(),
      q: params.term // search term
     };